# Should we heat up engines before driving a car?

Tags: road-vehicles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is running the engine for five minutes before driving beneficial for the car?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7061/is-running-the-engine-for-five-minutes-before-driving-beneficial-for-the-car)

My wife, her dad, and my dad says so.

They said that before you drive a car, you need to turn on the car for a few minutes, let the engine heat up, then drive.

My dad has a different theory. You don't need to heat up the engine, however, the engine oil is more well distributed when the car is running for a few minutes with no load.

Which one is right?

How it really works anyway?

Is it even true?